# Проблема с indexOf()

Tags: javascript, html

Возникла следующая проблема: код реагирует на ЛЮБОЕ значение, а должен только если там есть английские буквы и/или цифры

```
if(login.indexOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0")){
```

Comment: что значит реагирует?

Comment: ну конечно, а что вы хотели? вы просто пишите Login.indexof(;'''') И он работает.

Comment: Я думаю должно быть как то так if(login.indexof(blabla) === -1) или if(login.indexof(blabla) !== -1)

Comment: Исправил, при "=== -1" ничего не изменилось, при "!== -1" перестал работать (без ошибки в консоль)

Comment: Опишите что вы хотите получить

Comment: Хочу что бы при вводе данных, которые не содержат английские буквы и/или цифры (то есть все, за исключением английских букв и/или цифр) выдавало предупреждение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPD

Чтобы проверить логин на валидность (допустимы только английские буквы и цифры) можно использовать регулярное выражение.

```js
const login1 = 'приветhelloмир12';
const login2 = 'при#вет$мир^';

if (login1.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g) === null) {
  console.log('Первый логин не содержит английских букв и цифр!');
}

if (login2.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g) === null) {
  console.log('Второй логин не содержит английских букв и цифр!');
}
```

## ЛИБО

(Извращённый способ)

Проблема Ваша в том, что метод [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) принимает только два параметра (елемент, который нужно найти и индекс с которого надо начинать поиск). Поэтому мы не можем просто взять и написать `indexOf('a', 'b', ...)`, нам нужно сделать проверку для каждого символа отдельно.

```js
const login = 'прив#ет$ми!р';

// Допустимые символы
const az = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];

let warn = true;
az.forEach(function(sym) {
  // Мы должны проверить каждую букву из допустимых символов
  if (login.indexOf(sym) !== -1) {
    warn = false;
  }
});

if (warn) {
  console.log('Английских букв и цифр нету в логине!');
}
```

Comment: должен был быть синий кит а не голубой :)

Comment: да лааадно -_- @entithat

Comment: Сигнатура функции: `str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`. Так с какого перепуга в неё передаётся всё вот это `login.indexOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");`?? Не будет так работать. И `index && index !== -1` - тоже фигня. Чем 0 не угодил?

Comment: @entithat, ну я бы про indexOf текст оставил, да и пример, который не в сниппете. Как-то зря ты всё зачистил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, уже редактирую и с вариантом с indexOf